# I cannot install, repair o remove Oracle XE 11

Tags: oracle

good morning everyone. He tried to uninstall it and not let me. I uninstall the folder manually deleting records in Windows. But now when he tried reinstalling does not let me. I have only the options "repair" or "remove" and when I select tells me this (-1605: This action is only for products That are Currently installed) and (failed to launch app : Cleanup.bat), respectively. I've seen other post with the same problem, but all the solutions require using OUI Oracle folder, I've already erased. I do not know how to reinstall Oracle. Please help me. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly remove this folder from your machine C:\Program Files(x86)\Install Shield Information

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting folder C:\Program Files\InstallShield something

Answer (score 0):

there's going to be entries in your registry you need to remove. If you google "remove oracle manually from windows" you should find a solution

this may help
http://docs.oracle.com/html/B10131_02/deinstall.htm